# vs code + python + terminal run/debug pane too small - how to expand or run with shortcut in separate console window

Tags: python, terminal, console, themes

im running vs code 1.79.0, with the python extensions enabled on windows 10. I'm writing code in the code pane and below it, is a a "terminal" pane. when I run and debug, it launches a console and then runs the python code by calling python.exe . this then displays and scrolls in the terminal window.

My problem is that my app is kind of designed to be a square window with context menus for the various applets within the main app. So when I run it in the small rectangular terminal window, i only see about 1/2 of the context menus and cannot run it very well. Additionally, when the app is run by end user, it starts a new square cmd.exe console and runs in a separate window; and then exists by closing the console window.

So im trying to replicate the look and feel of this within VSCode. I don't see how to tear off the terminal window to run the app in it own window context. Is there a way to do that? seems like many users are complaining about this.

Given the lack of this feature, my next request is: how do i make a shortcut keystroke or menu bar item to launce "python.exe <MyCodeFile.ps"> I can do this within notepad++, with a "run" item which gets stored int he shortcuts.xml file. then I can press Alt+R for example and it fires up my script, which is in notepad but launces it in another console window, in the context of python.

lastly, I have a themes of light in general, but want to run the terminal in dark mode. is that possible?

Many thx in advance!

I searched far and wide for terminal tear off or keyboard shortcuts to launch "python " in separate window.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.